# Bathroom exhaust fan to blow air directly behind it (with no turns)?

Tags: exhaust-fan, ventilation

I need to add an exhaust fan to a bathroom. The layout is such that the fan will need to be in a wall, with the duct directly behind it. Ideally, the fan will take air into its grille, and send that air directly behind the fan, with no turns at all.

However, the exhaust fans I'm seeing all seem to turn the air 90°, after which I'd need to turn it 90° again to get it to go along my exhaust pipe.

**Is there a type of exhaust fan that would allow air to flow into the grille, and to continue into an exhaust pipe directly behind it, with no turns at all?**

Comment: you may need to refine your search terms a bit,

Comment: Maybe an "inline fan" is what you're after..?

Comment: Odd, the bathroom fan I installed a decade ago had the output in line with the fan, needing an elbow to redirect a few feet over to the roof outlet.

Comment: The OP is asking if a product exists, not to recommend one.

Comment: After some more research, I found there is a type of exhaust fan called "through the wall" or "through-wall".

Answer (score 2):

Google "mobile home bath fans".

There are many different types, some with lights.

Comment: This feels like a comment.

Answer (score -1):

Broam has a through the wall fan similar to the one shown below from Amazon. There are some fans listed as "vertical discharge" but they woud still have to be mounted in the ceiling.  This fan is designed to be installed into a wall and a duct can be attached straight to the back of it.

[image]

[https://www.amazon.com/Broan-512M-Through-Wall-6-Inch-Sones/dp/B000LNKUN8/ref=pd_lpo_sccl_1/138-5310468-5124342?pd_rd_w=6HS86&content-id=amzn1.sym.116f529c-aa4d-4763-b2b6-4d614ec7dc00&pf_rd_p=116f529c-aa4d-4763-b2b6-4d614ec7dc00&pf_rd_r=4364VW6VBXG9ZM6BX0X9&pd_rd_wg=wgCNN&pd_rd_r=3e23788d-999c-4d7a-9c8e-7634ebad9656&pd_rd_i=B000LNKUN8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000LNKUN8)